# How to calculate from a date to another date?

Tags: java, date, datetime, junit, calendar

I am creating a workday calendar which calculates which date the workday ends.
I have a code that sets daily worktime from e.g 8:00-16:00 (workDayStartStop).
And a code when given a start date and increment in days should print out which date .
Increment in workingdays could be e.g 1.5f (which means 8 + 4 hours working day) or 1.25f (8 + 2 working hours).

##Issues:

1. My code only prints the days and hours correctly, but it needs to calculate minutes too.
2. My code needs to calculate backwards too if negative values are provided in days to increment.

```
public void setWorkdayStartAndStop(Calendar start, 
      Calendar stop) {
      ZonedDateTime startZdt = ((GregorianCalendar) 
  start).toZonedDateTime();

    ZonedDateTime endZdt = ((GregorianCalendar) 
  stop).toZonedDateTime();

    long wholeDays = ChronoUnit.DAYS.between(startZdt, endZdt);

    startZdt = startZdt.plusDays(wholeDays);

    Duration workDay = Duration.between(startZdt, endZdt);

    this.workdayStartAndStop = (float) workDay.toMinutes() / 
    (float) Duration.ofHours(1).toMinutes();
  }

  public LocalDateTime getWorkdayIncrement(LocalDateTime 
    startDate, float incrementInWorkdays) {
    Holidays holidays = new Holidays();
    CalendarController cc = new CalendarController();
    holidays.setHolidayIfIsSetToRecurring();

    int days = (int) Math.abs(incrementInWorkdays);
    float remaining = incrementInWorkdays - days;
    float fHours = remaining * 24f;
    int hours = (int) fHours;

    remaining = fHours - hours;
    float fMinutes = remaining * 60f;
    int minutes = (int) fMinutes;

    LocalDateTime mDateTime = null;

    for (int i = 0; i <= days; i++) {
        mDateTime = 
    startDate.plusDays(i).plusHours(hours).plusMinutes(minutes);

        LocalDate toLocalDate = mDateTime.toLocalDate();

        //if the incremented day is a holiday, skip to nextday
        if (cc.isHoliday(toLocalDate)) {
            days += 1;
        }
    }
    return mDateTime;
}
}

 public static void main(String[] args) {
    WorkdayCalendar workdayCalendar = new WorkdayCalendar();

    workdayCalendar.setWorkdayStartAndStop(
            LocalDateTime.of(2020, 1, 1, 8, 0),
            LocalDateTime.of(2020, 1, 1, 16, 0));

    workdayCalendar.setRecurringHoliday(
            MonthDay.of(5, 17));

    workdayCalendar.setHoliday(LocalDate.of(2020, 5, 27));

    LocalDateTime start = LocalDateTime.of(2020, 5, 24, 8, 5);

    String datePattern = "dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm";
    DateTimeFormatter europeanDateFormatter = 
 DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(datePattern);

    float increment = 1.5f;

    System.out.println(
            europeanDateFormatter.format(start) +
                    " with the addition of " +
                    increment +
                    " working days is " +
                    europeanDateFormatter.format(workdayCalendar.getWorkdayIncrement(start, increment)));
}
```

### Output is:

**24-05-2020 08:05 with the addition of 1.5 working days is 26-05-2020 20:05**

starting 24th 8 o'clock in the morning it should end 25th 12 o'clock in the morning (8h + 4h) . 1 workday is only from 8-16, then it should skip to next day. it should only give results between 8-16 if startDate is set fra 08:00 and wokringhours is set to 8hours a day.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using outdated and broken date/time API which are confusing and error-prone. Use [modern date/time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-date-time.html) which are smart and intuitive:

```
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.Month;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.of(2020, Month.JUNE, 18, 21, 50, 5);
        System.out.println(ldt);

        // After 2.75 days
        System.out.println(getWorkdayIncrement(ldt, 2.75f));
    }

    public static LocalDateTime getWorkdayIncrement(LocalDateTime startDate, float incrementInWorkdays) {
        int days = (int) incrementInWorkdays;

        float remaining = incrementInWorkdays - days;
        float fhours = remaining * 24f;
        int hours = (int) fhours;

        remaining = fhours - hours;
        float fminutes = remaining * 60f;
        int minutes = (int) fminutes;

        return startDate.plusDays(days).plusHours(hours).plusMinutes(minutes);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
2020-06-18T21:50:05
2020-06-21T15:50:05
```

**[Update]**

Given below is how you can get `LocalDate` out of `MonthDay`:

```
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.Month;
import java.time.MonthDay;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Month-day of June, 20
        MonthDay monthDay = MonthDay.of(Month.JUNE, 20);
        LocalDate date = monthDay.atYear(2020);
        System.out.println(date);

        // Month-day now
        monthDay = MonthDay.now();
        date = monthDay.atYear(2020);
        System.out.println(date);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
2020-06-20
2020-06-20
```

Comment: thank you sir! How do I look up  a Monthday in a LocalDate?? I wanna compare a set of Monthday to a set of LocalDates. please see my updated code far down.

Comment: @RossoTheMan - I've updated the answer to incorporate this requirement. I hope, it helps. Feel free to comment in case of any doubt/issue.

Comment: I forgot HashSet removes duplicates so checking it contains is unecessary. But your solution helped me verify that and it did help a lot. again Thank you mister and i did not know i had to accept things. will look into that :)

Comment: I get Nullpointer inside getWorkdayIncrement when I provide a negative value of workdaysdays in the parameter.
The Nullpointer exception is thrown during 'atZone()' when returned the Date. See updated getworkdayIncrement().

Comment: Replace `int days = (int) incrementInWorkdays;` with `int days = (int) Math.abs(incrementInWorkdays);`

Comment: IT worked but hovering over atZone() still says "method invocation may produce nullpointer exception "  how to avoid that?

Comment: When setting getWorkIncremnt startDate from 18:00 (24hours) it should end 18:00,but instead it ends 06:00 in the morning. what is this ? Im using simpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH-mm);

Comment: Use `DateTimeFormatter` instead of `SimpleDateFormat`. You will keep facing such problems until you switch to the [modern date-time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-date-time.html). I recommend you stop using the date-time API of `java.util` package and switch to date-time API of `java.time` package and its sub-packages.

Comment: I changed to DateTimeFormatter but its still the same. Please see my updated getWorkdayIncrement().    it doesnt calculate hour or minutes correctly. When Start is set  from 08.00 o'clock  24th and i Increment for 1.5 days it should end 26th 12:00 clock (half day 8-12)

Comment: `08.00 o'clock 24th + 1 day = 08.00 o'clock 25th` and `08.00 o'clock 25th + 1/2 day = 08.00 o'clock 25th + 12 hours = 08.00 pm 25th` in AM/PM format or `20.00 o'clock 25th` in 24-hour format. Why do you think, it should be `26th 12:00 clock`?

Comment: I added main example with details

Comment: Replace `float fhours = remaining * 24f;` with `float fhours = remaining * 8f;` because you are considering one day as 8 hours instead of 24 hours.

Comment: perfect! I ow you big time!